# Iterate through an array of values of yaml data

Tags: ansible

I have the output of a command:

```
---
data:
  versions:
    - alt-php53
    - ea-php56
    - ea-php72
metadata:
  command: php_get_installed_versions
  reason: OK
  result: 1
  version: 1
```

And I need to iterate through the values of the **versions** key.

I have this to assign the output to a variable:

```
- name: Get PHP versions
  shell: "/usr/sbin/whmapi1 php_get_installed_versions"
  register: eaphp_versions
```

But I do not know how exactly to iterate through those values. I tried various methods with dict2items, from_yaml, from_yaml_all using loop, I tried sub_elements but none worked.

The closest I got is the below:

```
- name: 'Apply stuff'
  shell: "echo the item is {{ item }} >> report.txt"
  loop: "{{ eaphp_versions.stdout | from_yaml_all | list }}"
```

But judging from the output it iterates through the whole output as one item:

```
the item is {udata: {uversions: [ualt-php53, uea-php56, uea-php72]}, umetadata: {ureason: uOK, uversion: 1, ucommand: uphp_get_installed_versions, uresult: 1}}
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the data structure at top the contents from eaphp_versions?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this myself. Here it is below how I did it.

```
- name: Set fact
  set_fact:
    versions: "{{ versions|default({})|combine(item) }}"
  loop: "{{ eaphp_versions.stdout | from_yaml_all|list }}"

- name: 'Set PHP memory_limit to 512M (all PHP versions)'
  #40
  shell: "/usr/sbin/whmapi1 php_ini_set_directives directive-1=memory_limit%3A512M version={{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ versions.data.versions }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the data structure at top are the contents from eaphp_versions, then you can:

```
- any-your-module:
    any-module-params: use of {{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ eaphp_versions.data.versions }}"
```

The {{ item }} is one of the 3 versions.

Comment: this is what I got when I tried your suggestion:
`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'data'"}`